# Cordova - Playing mp3 files in android "res/raw" and iOS resources

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, playback

I know how to play mp3 files in both Cordova Android and iOS if they are located in "assets" folder.

In this case I would like to play the mp3 files which I use for notification.

They are respectively located in:
Android: "res/raw"
iOS: "resources"

Is there a possibility to play them in their respective location without having to copy them in "assets/www/..." ?

Which location should I refer to in my "play" command for ios and which for Android?

Tried several options but no luck...

Any permission needed at app level?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to play the mp3 used for notifications.

So to recap:

1- iOS Notification: I copy (hook) from my asset folder, the relevant mp3 into

```
myApp/platforms/ios/myApp/Resources
```

2- Android Notification: I copy mp3 into

```
myApp/platforms/android/myApp/res/raw
```

3- To be able to play those mp3 I copy them into folder

```
myApp/www
```

Not optimal because, it uses twice as much the space for mp3 in installation files but it works...